# Python convert one column data into multiple columns

Tags: python

The question i have is:
I have a dataset that looks like this (let's say there is one variable called "ChatConversations" and another called CustomerID) and that has the text of the chat for each customer. Suppose, there are 1000 customers, so my dataset has 1000 rows with 2 columns, one for CustomerID and another for the Chattranscript. Suppose each customer has 2 sentences each. So, i want to create a new dataset/file, which has 2000 sentences appended to each other, like a paragraph,which i will then read and do text mining on.

Hopefully my question is clear

[image: Input Data Like below]

Output data like below:
I love thes service.IT took time.The issue was resolved, so I don’t have complaints.The agent couldn’t understand what I said.Grett job no complaints.Can do better (basically all the values of the "ChatCOnversation" variable need to be joined together to create a paragraph/text file kind of thing

Comment: Hint: a question normally has a question mark... your question does not other than the implicit "could someone write this code for me?"

Answer (score 1):

<del>You could make a dictionary for each row which you create by zipping a list of column headlines and each data line together and store those in a list, like this:</del>

```
headlines = ["India", "Asia", "Singapore", "Malaysia", "Nepal", "China"]
dict_list = []
with open("my_file.csv") as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        dict_list.append(dict(zip(hl, [item.strip() for item in line.split(",")])))  
print(*dict_list, sep="\n")  # print one dictionary per line
```

---

### Update:

You probably want just something like this:

```
with open("input.csv") as in_file, open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
   for line in in_file:
        content = line.split(",", 1)[1].strip()
        print(content, file=out_file)
```

Comment: You have to be more specific. You can of course load this list of headlines from a file. Or you could not use any headlines at all but just numeric indices for the columns, that would be a list then instead of a dictionary. Please be more specific on what you want.

Comment: I guess it would be the best to edit your question and include a small example of input and output files, each with let's say 2 or 3 data rows. I can't really get what you're trying to tell me yet...

Comment: Hi ByteCommander, did the above help? Please let me know, else i can change per your request

Comment: @kaos1511 Unfortunately not. First, a text file does not contain any variables. It only contains lines of text. Also I asked you for a short input/output example consisting of 2 or 3 data rows which you did not provide.

Comment: @kaos1511 I updated my answer, does that fit your needs?